# Getting first element from PDOStatement

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am performing an sql query using PDO. In the resulting PDOStatement, there is only one column. If i use `PDOStatement->fetch();` would it serve my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, although [fetchColumn](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)() would probably be more convenient as the return value will be scalar.

```
echo $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

otherwise you could do the following, or many variations of

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
echo $row[0];
```

Comment: Im new to php. What do you mean by scalar?

Comment: i guess "single, simple, value" would be a description. strings, numbers, booleans are scalar for example. most of the time you get arrays back from databases, and arrays aren't scalar because they're a group of values, not a single value. anyway, don't think too much about it, just use what you're comfortable with.